# Is it possible to run openfoam from a bash script in an org-mode sourceblock?

Tags: bash, emacs, org-mode, openfoam, org-babel

I have an org-mode document and would like to run openfoam from a sourceblock. As OS I use Windows 10 where I have openfoam installed in an Ubuntu WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux) environment.

Basically I think that bash scripts are recognized and executed correctly by org, because this example gives correct output:

```
#+begin_src bash :results output
  lsb_release -a
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
: Description:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
: Release:  20.04
: Codename: focal
```

But this code block here returns an error message

```
#+begin_src bash :results output
  gmshToFoam geometry.msh
#+end_src

bash: line 1: gmshToFoam: command not found
```

I suspect that an environment variable is missing because the command is not recognized. When I start the Linux shell manually the command is recognized. Is it possible that the $HOME/.bashrc file is not loaded by org?

Comment: org executes shell blocks using `shell`.  My guess is you installed `openfoam` and  haven't logged out/logged back in, which may be necessary before emacs picks up changes to your environment (depending on how your launching emacs).  You could `echo $PATH` to check if it is what you expect it to be, and if not logout/login.

Comment: Hi @Rorschach

your answer is definitely in the right direction. When I run an echo $PATH in the WSL terminal I get 7 entries which belong to openFOAM and Paraview which are not listed in the PATH of the emacs shell.

There are all PATH entries to Linux relevant directories like /bin and /sbin, as well as all my Windows paths. Only the ones from openFOAM are missing.

But it can't be the relog, because I have rebooted the computer several times since the installation.

Comment: I don't use windows, so not familiar with your setup.  Are you running emacs as a windows application, or in the WSL?  If necessary, you can add the paths using some elisp, but that shouldnt be necessary normally.  The logout/login would only be applicable to the linux part

Comment: Personally, I would load environment variables in `.profile` so they get inherited by gui programs that aren't launched from the shell- which isnt always the case for `.bashrc` depending on the linux distribution/version

Comment: As a test, if you try launcing emacs from the bash shell in wsl, eg. `emacs &` or `emacsclient -nc -a ""`, it should inherit the `PATH` you've set in your ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I have emacs as windows version and in parallel a ubuntu in WSL.

It looks like an org-mode source block partially recognizes the bash, but does not take over all settings. As mentioned above, /bin/ and so on are in the PATH, only the manually added paths not.

For testing I installed emacs in WSL and printed the PATH there. This seems to be correct. Unfortunately it seems to be not so trivial to set up emacs in WSL, because org-mode does not recognize a bash block in WSL.

The easiest thing for me would be to get emacs to process the .bashrc and/or .profiles file.

Comment: Oh, and it doesn't seem to make any difference if I add the paths to .bashrc or .profile, emacs doesn't recognize either of them.

Comment: `.profile` is read when ubuntu 20's gnome windows manager starts up, so gui programs, like emacs, inherit the environment variables defined there, but it doesnt read .bashrc by default (it doesnt launch with bash)- since your running emacs as a Windows application, however, this doesn't matter, and emacs won't know anything about the environment variables in either of those files.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but if you read the `C-h f` `shell` doc, you can define a `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME` file that may be useful.  Alternatively, the paths can be set in emacs using `setenv` and modifying the `exec-path` variable.  On macOS, I hear people use this library to sync their PATH from the shell, https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell/blob/master/exec-path-from-shell.el although I've never needed it on linux

Comment: So, I have found out a few things in the last 2 days: 1.) The variable _explicit-shell-file-name_ is correctly recognized for the M-x _shell_ command. The _shell-command_ command M-! seems to ignore this variable completely. 2.) On Windows, a "shell" sourc-block seems to be linked to the Windows cmd.exe, whereas a "bash" accesses the WSL, but ignores the .bashrc file.

Comment: 3.) A shell codeblock with the option :shebang #!/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/bash.exe -i looks promising. Because then I get an error message saying that the file C:/Users/.../Temp/babel-xxyyzz/sh-script-zzyyxx does not exist, which is correct if it is the WLS terminal. There the path should be /mnt/c/Users/.../Temp/babel-xxyyzz/sh-script-zzyyxx.

Comment: The question now is, how do I make org-mode set the temp path for shell scripts with :shebang option different from the rest of the code blocks.